# Searching for book on Ibn Arabi

Tags: reference-request, ontology

I'm looking for this book: The mystical philosophy of Muhyiddin Ibn Arabi  by Afifi. Could anyone help?

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/philosophyofibna033258mbp/philosophyofibna033258mbp_djvu.txt

Comment: Thanks for replying, the site you referred me to does not contain the book I'm after. This  one is written by Rom  Landau, not Affifi.

Comment: sorry about that. I found a used copy in Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/mystical-philosophy-Muhyid-Din-Ibnul-Arabi/dp/B0006CIUZE/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1500399212&sr=8-4-fkmr0&keywords=The+mystical+philosophy+of+Muhyiddin+Ibn+Arabi

Answer (score 1):

*The Mystical Philosophy Of Muhyid Din-ibnul Arabi*, by A. E. Affifi

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.171931